# Python электронная подпись

Tags: python, цифровая-подпись

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться с вопросом.
Рассмотрим такой случай, у моей программы есть пользователи и я отправлю файлы, программа у пользователя считывает эти данные.
Хочу проверить данные от подмены. Для этого с данными отправляю хэш(в файле) передаваемого файла что бы сравнить.
Теперь как защитить этот файл с хэшом?
 1. Асимметричное шифрование - для этого мне в программе нужно держать приватный ключ чтобы расшифровать. Тогда могут дикомпелировать программу и узнать приватный ключ, далее публичный и подменять данные.
 2. Электронная подпись которая шифрует приватным и расшифровывает публичным, вариант вроде подходящий, но как применить это не ясно, что бы в python проверять хэш.
Получилось подписать файл, но для этого я использовал в Window (makecert.exe и signtool.ex) а как это сделать средствами python или может быть есть другой вариант для шифрования закрытым ключом.
Спасибо.

Comment: Проверка на сервере, доступном только вам, или как? И хотите защититься от подмены кем?

Comment: Допустим я на сервер выкладываю данные, программа у пользователя качает данные и проверяет что бы они были те которые положил я. И сервер доступен не только мне, то есть права на запись и чтение есть у всех.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я использовал библиотеку [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io) (поскольку pycrypto, похоже, больше не поддерживается).

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15
import os


fname ="Путь к файлу"

# Генерируете новый ключ (или берете ранее сгенерированный)
key = RSA.generate(1024, os.urandom)
# Получаете хэш файла
h = SHA256.new()
with open(fname, "rb") as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
        h.update(chunk)

# Подписываете хэш
signature = pkcs1_15.new(key).sign(h)

# Получаете открытый ключ из закрытого
pubkey = key.publickey()

# Пересылаете пользователю файл, публичный ключ и подпись
# На стороне пользователя заново вычисляете хэш файла (опущено) и сверяете подпись
pkcs1_15.new(pubkey).verify(h, signature)

# Отличающийся хэш не должен проходить проверку
pkcs1_15.new(pubkey).verify(SHA256.new(b'test'), signature) # raise ValueError("Invalid signature")
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @beginning_user это вас никак не защитит: по дороге если вы предполагаете, что файл могут поменять, то также могут поменять и хэш и ключ.

Comment: @jfs Проверка проходит в самой программе, то есть я передаю только файл и хэш, ключ будет вшит в программу. Не зная закрытого ключа получается не смогут подписать файл что бы он прошел проверку.

Comment: @beginning_user: если у вас есть безопасный канал, чтобы программу и ключ передать, то что мешает по этому же каналу и сам файл передать?

Comment: @ jfs Пока буду считать что я сам устанавливаю программу. Если фактом установки пренебречь, то такой подход с передачей файлов по незащищенному каналу можно считать безопасным?

Comment: @beginning_user если у пользователя есть возможность изменения исходного кода программы, то любая защита бесполезна, он всё равно сможет использовать тот файл, который хочет. Если доступа к изменению программы нет, то вшитый публичный ключ становится достаточной защитой. Разве что защититься от подмены файла после проверки (проверять каждый раз при чтении, например).

Comment: @jfs, если я правильно понял, у beginning_user проблема не с тем, чтобы безопасно передать файл, а с тем, чтобы убедиться, что пользователь использует конкретный файл и не подменяет его другим. Если мы предполагаем, что пользователь может залезть в python-скрипт и что-то там поменять - нас ничто не спасет, если же пользователь поменять скрипт не может - схема с подписью становится безопасна. Возможно я не учел каких-то факторов, но пока не вижу где ещё пользователь сможет подсунуть неверный файл вместо правильного, ведь закрытого ключа у пользователя по определению нет.

Comment: @beginning_user если считать что программа с публичным ключом магическим образом на компьютере пользователя материализуются (но этот магический способ для самого файла недоступен), то проверка уже в конкретные алгоритмы упирается (сложнее сломать).

Answer (score 1):

А я использую ctypescrypto. Работать без абстракции классов сложно, но возможности шире. Пока еще не видел проект на питоне, который покрыл бы абстракциями удобными для питона всю OpenSSL.

Ctypescrypto выбрал потому, что нигде не смог получить поддержку загрузки плагинов - тоесть поддержку GOST.

Вот пример подписи

```
from ctypescrypto.engine import Engine,set_default
from ctypescrypto.cms import SignedData,Flags
from ctypescrypto.pkey import PKey    
from ctypescrypto.x509 import X509

set_default(Engine('gost'))


req = """data to sign"""

with open('/home/eri/Projects/rkn/provider.pem','rb') as f:
    d = f.read()

cert = X509(d) # сертификат с приватным ключем в формате pem в переменной d, загружаю сертификат
p = cert.pubkey

pk = PKey(privkey=d) # приватный ключ

mes = SignedData.create(req, cert, pk, flags=Flags.DETACHED+Flags.BINARY)

with open('req.txt.sig','wb') as f:
    f.write(mes.pem())

with open('req.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write(req)
```